# Strange behaviour how Forfiles treat swedish

Tags: batch-file, codepages, forfiles

`Forfiles` with swedish characters don't work smothless...

I use a Swedish computer and the `Forfiles` treat swedish characters very strange. It can treat one instans correct and in the next be stupid. I have struggled with this problem for a long time and I think I have found a solution and my experience (none) tells me that it is the different operations in the forfiles that make it tough.

I have to use `CHCP 65001` in my batch file to make it work. All `forfiles` work with this codepage except for the `CALL`. Then it gets into trouble.

My solution then was to change just that part to CHCP `1252`. Didn't work perfectly, but when I took it all and directed it into a "some textfile.txt" file then all of a sudden everything works. Now I can use swedish characters in foldernames.

It seems that the `CALL` argument needs a special codepage to work, but using it on the rest of the code will fail...

Have one question though: Why does it behave this strange and why do I need to put an `>myfile.txt` at the end to make it work?

`    CHCP 65001

```
forfiles /S /m * /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE COPY myfile.bat @path"`
```

(This works even if the folders have swedish characters (`åäö`), but will fail using codepage 1252. Myfile.bat is placed in every folder and builds an html page of the folders content when is CALLed below).

`    CHCP 1252

```
forfiles /S /m "myfile.bat" /c "cmd /c CALL @path" >> some textfile.txt`
```

(This will fail using codepage 65001, but works perfect with codepage 1252. It need the `>some textfile, without it, it will fail. Build the pages in each folder.)

`DEL some textfile.txt`

(The file is deleted since it is just garbage (Strange that I need this file))

`CHCP 65001`

(Changing back to codepage 65001 to make everything else work. Below code builds a linkpage to every folder found and is the same on every page being created.)

`forfiles /S /m * /c "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE ECHO @path" >>anotherfile.txt`

(Thank you for all of your answers. I will rebuild it now when I know a little bit more. Small stepps, small stepps... )

Comment: Support for code page 65001 in the console is relatively new and still [a work in progress](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/11/15/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/), and older programs may not have been updated to support it.

Comment: Why do you use `forfiles`? The only reason for using `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe` instead of internal command `for` is on using `forfiles` option `/D`. In all other cases `for` is the better choice. For example run in a Windows command prompt window `for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /AD /B /S "%ProgramFiles%" 2^>nul') do @echo %~sI`. This command line outputs all directories including those with hidden attribute set found in program files directory using __short__ name of each found folder. Your character encoding problem should not occur at all by using short full qualified folder name.

Comment: __Short__ names in 8.3 format consist of only ASCII characters. Run a command with `/?` as parameter in a command prompt window to get displayed its help. Try that out with `forfiles /?`, `for /?`, `dir /?` and `call /?`. The command `help` outputs a list of [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) documented better on [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/).